# Are the parents of EU blue card holder eligible for family reunion Visa?

Tags: visas, germany, family

I have a question regarding family reunion visa for Germany.

If an unmarried individual has the EU blue card, are the his/her parents eligible for a family reunion visa?

I've read that the spouse and children are eligible but can't find much information about the parents.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- §36 AufenthG says that an Aufenthaltserlaubnis *may* be granted to parents of a resident in Germany if not doing so would be an undue hardship. §36 ("kann", "may") is much weaker language than e.g. §30 ("ist ... zu erteilen", "shall be granted").
- There are special rules when the resident in Germany is a minor refugee without any other guardian in Germany. Presumably a blue card holder is older than that.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know what kind of proofs the applicant should introduce to proof such '"hardship"?

Comment: @MinaSamy, no idea, best ask on Expatriates SE.

Comment: @Mina In general this is about the parent being very sick and not having anyone at home to care for them. Simply being in a country where there is no comparable health care to Germany will not be enough though. This thing is only for very very very rare cases.